# Comparing packet timestamps and finding delay

Tags: java

So I'm using DataOutputStreams to hold the current timestamps of packets.

**Client Side:**

```
    byte[] tempBuffer = recorder.getBlock();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.write(tempBuffer);
    dos.writeLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dos.flush();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(baos.toByteArray(), baos.size(), clientIP, PORT);
```

**Server Side:**

```
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    receiving_socket.receive(packet);
    long received  =System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] udpPacketBytes = packet.getData();
    ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(udpPacketBytes);
    DataInputStream dos = new DataInputStream(baos);
    long timeSend = dos.readLong();
    System.out.println(received- timeSend);
```

So I want to find the difference of the times for when the packet was sent to when it was actually retrieved.

**The output I'm currently getting is as follows:**

```
-144336931610443142
-6413368508412665479
-9223293613480097670
-3242630961109421321
-1657385879957442570
1445848312512800754
4030252469527785967
3672742989582189418
2660264248110580060
8210679245661657192
-7276041996288176391
-7783862498534639127
-6198549255261902107
```

This can't be right? How can the packet be received before it was sent? I'm sure I'm coding this wrong, any pointers would be great, thank you

EDIT:

**Received Output:**

```
System.out.println(received);
```

-

```
    1456672303102
    1456672303222
    1456672303222
    1456672303222
    1456672303223
    1456672303348
    1456672303348
    1456672303348
    1456672303348
    1456672303474
```

Comment: Are you testing it on the same machine?

Comment: No, two machines @JorgeCampos

Comment: the number looks like nanoseconds not millis, did you try outputing `received`. In the posted code, you write some buffer before the time, but when reading you read only the time, so I assume the datayou get in readLong are from the buffer and then you get some overflow

Comment: I printed out the received time @RC. check edit. Yeah so the readLong() retrieves the value of the time which was put in the packet prior to sending

Comment: Are the two machines in the same timezone? and if so, are they with the clock with the same time?

Comment: I've wrote the answer, thanks for your help andway @JorgeCampos

Answer (score 0):

Didn't prepare for the extra bytes required for the writeLong() on the receiver side. Required a byte array of 520, I had a byte array of 512